# Unable to install cocoapods on Mac m1

Tags: macos, cocoapods

I'm unable to uninstall the Cocoapods from my system which is MacBook Air M1 2020

When I run the command **"sudo gem uninstall cocoapods"** I get this response **"Gem 'cocoapods' is not installed"**

and when I run **"pod --version"** I get the version number **"1.12.1"**

I'm on MacOS 13.6

How to completely remove the Cocoapods from my system?